# What is the correct way to modularize DialogFragment usage?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I started creating a DialogFragment class before realizing that the DialogFragment can also be seen as a sort of wrapper to make other fragments "popuppable".

Is there a way to invoke another Fragment in the DialogFragment? I ask because I want to make a particular screen to be in a popup, but I want it to be its own fragment in case I decide later to make it (for example) part of a ViewPager instead, or some other use.

Comment: Please, Don't ask question where answer need to be some what kind of essay to explain as it will either get down voted or closed, Just show what you have done so far and where you are stuck with proper errors/code and snapshots.    `Yes, you can nest any number of fragment one into another`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do that. DialogFragment is a Fragment so you can call `getChildFragmentManager()` instead of `getSupportFragmentManager()` or `getFragmentManager()`.

Comment: If you make a fragment in a fragment in a fragment in a fragment in a... etc, do you just use getChildFragmentManager() for all of these? And then getActivity() still refers to the base activity the first fragment was attached to?

Comment: YES, but nesting fragments has bugs on retaining it on configuration changes. Check here https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=74222 they will fix it soon as posted on the issue and there is a workaround also. It's a big issue that you need to be aware of before starting.

Comment: So if I have a fragment inside a fragment, and rotate the screen, the nested fragment will not retain state even if I use something like onSave/onRestoreInstanceState() or whatever the equivalent is for fragments?

Comment: Yes indeed. the whole child fragment manager will get destroyed.

Comment: What do you think is the best workaround for the moment?

Comment: Check this blog post http://ideaventure.blogspot.com.au/2014/10/nested-retained-fragment-lost-state.html